# When inserting syntax code into `<pre>` elements ckeditor auto closes tag

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

When inserting code into `<pre>` elements in CKEditor it picks up on strongly type objects like

```
public IQueryable<Post> PostArchive
```

it then adds a closing tag `<post/>` tag which messes up the syntax highlighting.

Any help please.

Tried `config.allowedContent = true;` in ckeditor but with no luck..

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you're not encoding code correctly.

This is how your data should look like:

```
<pre>
public IQueryable&lt;Post&gt; PostArchive
</pre>
```

Note that `<Post>` has to be transformed to `&lt;Post&gt;`, because otherwise it is a custom HTML tag and that's why parse tries to fix it.